# Is there a way to integrate Gradle / Cucumber / Selenium tests into Browserstack (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber, browserstack

I have inherited a framework that uses Cucumber to use a series of browser-based tests with Selenium, in Java. The framework is currently built using Gradle and this works well.

I would very much like to integrate this whole thing with Browserstack, but the only Gradle plugin that I can find ([here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.browserstack.gradle)) is for Espresso, and so not applicable to my issue. I have also found another repository ([here](https://github.com/browserstack/cucumber-java-browserstack)) which does exactly what I want, but does so through Maven.

Note I am unfamiliar with both Gradle and Maven and hence am inclined to stick with the solution that is currently running and wary of unnecessary change. Bearing this in mind, I have the following questions:

1. Is there a published way to integrate Cucumber (Java) with Browserstack using Gradle?
2. If not, is converting from Gradle to Maven really as trivial as [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa) makes me believe? Is there anything else I must be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your queries:

1- I am not aware of any published documentation to integrate Cucumber (Java) with Browserstack using Gradle

2- In the link that you have shared( https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa), it says that you can convert maven to gradle in one step.

Run the command:
gradle init

In the directory containing the POM. This will convert the Maven build to a Gradle build, generating a settings.gradle file and one or more build.gradle files.

3-You have also shared the link: https://github.com/browserstack/cucumber-java-browserstack which uses maven.
You can follow the steps and easily convert maven to gradle

Comment: Thank you - I was trying to get a second opinion on this, as I said. Looks like I'll be going that way. I will post once this is successful.